# Installing Laravel while there are 2 php packages installed

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel

I have to install Laravel 4 on an old server which has Ubuntu 10.04 server installed with LAMP (PHP v5.3.10). I have ran the following commands;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-json php5-mcrypt
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php5
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
Problem 1 
laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled it with different commands to no avail. I know that the laravel installer is referring to the LAMP's installed PHP package. By checking versions;

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar  5 2012 18:10:34)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

php5 -v
PHP 5.4.33-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1 (cli) (built: Sep 19 2014 11:21:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

How can i make it to refer to the newer php5 package instead of the old one? I can't update the LAMP package as many other projects are being run on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Laravel problem. Laravel is executed by PHP, which is executed by Apache.

So you need to configure your Apache virtual host to do this for you, here's a virtual hosts file to run two different versions of PHP in the same host, which might should help you start solving your problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testphp540.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www 
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler php-cgi .php
        Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.4.0
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testphp550.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />virtual host
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler php-cgi .php
        Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.5.0
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testphp556.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler php-cgi .php
        Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.5.6
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the full HOW TO: http://www.distrogeeks.com/install-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu-lamp-server/. And searching on google "running multiple php versions" should also help you.